# Write remove method at index based on iterator equivalent from java to c#

Tags: java, c#, iterator, sequences

I am trying to write the equivalent method from java. MyIterator extends Iterator.

```
public T remove(int index) {
    MyIterator<T> it = support.iterator();//returns iterator over my sequence implementation
    int i = 0;
    T e = null;
    while (it.hasNext() && i < index) {
        e = it.next();
        i++;
    }
    it.remove();
    return e;
}
```

How can I write this to c# since there is no defined method for it.remove?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @KErlandsson just edited my post

Comment: You'll have to explain what `support` is and what equivalent you're planning to use in C#.

Comment: Sounds alot like [`Enumerable.Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#/.Net iterators ([`IEnumerator<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as returned by [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ) are read-only forward only iterators and do not allow removing items from underlying collection compared to [Java's iterator.remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Most collections support removing items by index like [`List<T>.RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which would be close equivalent.

Alternatively if you just want to skip item during iteration - `Enumarable.Skip` or [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can be an option:

```
   mySequence.Where((item,id) => id != indexToSkip)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public T remove<T>(int index)
{
    IEnumerator it = support.GetEnumerator();
    T e = default(T);
    int i = 0;
    while (it.MoveNext() && i < index)
    {
        e = (T)it.Current;
        i++;
    }

    // Have to remove from the original array here because iterators are read-only
    support.RemoveAt(index);
    return e;
}
```

I think that would be a literal translation, however there are much easier ways to do this depending on the type of array I'm sure.